# Playing mp4 video in webview using html5 in android

Tags: html, video, android-webview

I'm trying to play mp4 video in **webView** using **HTML5** in android but unfortunately it's not working, So can anyone help me, how can i do it ?

Here is my code
**HTML** file with name new2.html

```
<video width="365" height="200" src="/sdcard/Download/video.mp4" controls autobuffer></video>


<!--<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="/sdcard/Download/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>-->
```

**Java** file is:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
     WebView wv;  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.web_activity);  

         wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
         wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new2.html");
         wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
         wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        // webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");
    }

}
```

**XML** file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the video tag references a local file (on /sdcard). I'm wondering if that's allowed (even though you're invoking a web view through a native app). If you replace that local file with a URL on a local server, does the video play? If it does, then that's a clue that you have a permissions/access problem.

Comment: you say "not working". can you elaborate? Did you enable hardware acceleration (see http://gist.github.com/3718414 for an example)

Comment: @ Offbeatmammal I tried that too but it's not working means i'm getting a screen of 365*200 along with the controls play pause,seek,full screen etc of videoview but the screen is empty. I tried with .mp4 and swf both are not playing.

Comment: @ Multimedia Mike that's not my requirement i wanna play the video from local sd card using html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your file through local host --  file://localhost/ -- otherwise your phone will not recognize that it is you asking for permissions. By using your browser without localhost you are pinging off a satellite and can not make it back on re-rentry.

You are getting the controls to display because they come from a public html folder, but your source ( the video ) does not.

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog](http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html) it states there are two steps:

1. Create new class that extends ContentProvider and override essentially 1 method openFile. Method onCreate can be empty returning true and the rest can just throw UnsupportedOperationException.
2. Add a provider entry to AndroidManifest.xml.

[This page shows](http://www.techjini.com/blog/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/) how to do it as well - a summary from that page follows:

Step 1: Declare your Content Provider in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider android:name="MyDataContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.techjini" />
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ change this
```

Step 2:

Create your `ContentProvider` and implement `openFile`.
All you have to do is get real path from uri, open it and return the descriptor

```
URI uri = URI.create("file:///data/data/com.techjini/files/myImage.jpeg");
                              ^^^^^your path to your file    
File file = new File(uri);
ParcelFileDescriptor parcel =
    ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
return parcel;
```

You can find out where your image is stored using:

```
System.out.println(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

You can now load the file:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("content://com.techjini/myImage.jpeg");
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^change to same as in manifest
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change "/sdcard/Download/video.mp4" to "file:///sdcard/Download/video.mp4"? I mean the html part:

```
<video width="365" height="200" src="file:///sdcard/Download/video.mp4" controls autobuffer></video>
```

I couldn't open the html page in a custom web app. However I noticed that without adding "file:///" the video wouldn't play in my android browser. (In my case by adding "file:///" it took some time before the video started loading.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="365" height="200" src="video.mp4" controls autobuffer></video>
```

and the video.mp4 should be in your assets folder, the same place where you are putting your new2.html

Answer (score 0):

To play MP4 video in WebView, you need to first declare Content Provider in Manifest

```
<provider android:name = "MyDataContentProvider" android:authorities="com.myapp" />
```

Implement open file with `open()` method −

```java
URI myURL = URI.create("file:///mypath/new.mp4");
File f = new File(myURL);
ParcelFileDescriptor p =
   ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
return p;
```